# What is the difference between Express file structure and the Yeoman file structure?

Tags: express, yeoman

I'm trying to deploy a yeoman application on aws but having trouble. I've deployed on aws with express so I know it's possible. Can someone explain the difference in their file structure to me so that I can migrate my yeoman app to an express app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeoman dont are one app, Yeoman are one tool for generate project structures example:
you can use Yeoman to make one wordpress or Express.js project structures and may have a lot of diferente generators for same tecnology

And Express.js is an Node.js framework and you can use the express cli to generate your express app.

Then Yeoman and express is different things and is hard to help you change your project generated with Yeoman for be like one express project because may have a lot of possible structures